# How can I avoid rtmp disconnections?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a .swf that I embed inside a visualforce page (using swfobject) that records from your webcam and streams (publishes) it to a server over rtmp/rtmpt :1935, 443, or 80.

This swf requires a constant connection between client and server.

I get disconnected from my server very often. Most times I can't publish for more than a minute.

When the swf is run anywhere else (locally, from an S3-hosted page, from a node.js server, etc), it'll work fine and won't drop connection, so the problem is specifically with Salesforce.

What is causing this? How can I stop/avoid/work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Houseman I don't really think this is related to SFDC. The influence SFDC has on your SWF object should be minimal - *unless some portion of the page is being refreshed by Salesforce?* There is a lot going on under-the-covers with your typical VF pages. Since you can't control all the elements of the page - there is no way to change this.

Perhaps an iFrame to your SWF component would be a better option and see if it's stable.

Comment: I put it in an iFrame, and the problem still occurs. I was wrong, the problem was with my server, but this helped me figure that out.

Comment: @Houseman I've spent a lot of time messing with RTMP and some of the servers PING me: _myusernamehere_ @ gmail.com if you'd like to talk shop ... stuff definitely interests me! I know some experts as well.